# WooCommerce Subscription - Notice translation is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation, woocommerce-subscriptions

WooCommerce notice is not getting translated even if I add Japanese ( ja ) msg in .po/.mo file [PoEdit]

> Complete checkout to resubscribe.

```
if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() != 0 ) {
       wc_add_notice( __( 'Complete checkout to resubscribe', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ), 'success' );
 }
```

I went through the code, it's passing through the translation function. Switched to different languages from wp-admin. Nothing worked.
Any solutions.?

Comment: How exactly did you add it? Screenshot?

Comment: It is possible to take a screenshot of the message showing as translated

Comment: @mujuonly can you check your text domain? is it  woocommerce-subscriptions?

Comment: @jigarhalani https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/includes/class-wcs-cart-resubscribe.php#L91

Comment: can you go in plugin main file and add or update Text Domain: woocommerce-subscriptions @mujuonly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. My translation files where not getting updated via `poedit` when clicking on "Update from Sources"
Actually there was an error in "`includes/class-wc-subscriptions-change-payment-gateway.php`" #L41 file saying incorrect - As I checked the double-quotes symbol was seems like inverted double quote symbol. After correcting it and updating the po and saving, the translation got reflected in the site.